# Overfull \hbox warning

Tags: compiling

How do I fix the overfull `\hbox` warning from the following code?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage[paperheight=16000pt,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=16cm]{geometry} % for autocue

\begin{document}
\color{white} % for autocue
\pagecolor{black} % for autocue

\vspace{-10em}

\section{Lecture 1}
\noindent \textbf{Introduction: the learning goals}

\bigskip

\noindent In previous lectures we did an analysis of a simple two-player co-operative game called the Off Switch Game. What we want to do next is analyze a generalization of that to a more complicated type of game. There are quite a few different definitions in game theory of exactly what a ``game'' is, but we won't get into that. We're just going to work our way towards a precise definition of the class of games that we want to investigate: The Supervision Partially Observable Markov Decision Process, or ``Supervision POMDP''.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Who or what is autocue? With a normal page, no warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options

- Larger line width, it relaxes the demands of line breaking.
- `\usepackage{microtype}` right at the beginning of the preamble to
  get the HZ algorithm with more variable letter widths. That makes it easier for TeX to find break points.
- A font for narrow columns like Times Roman.
- Without justification: `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight` of package `ragged2e`.
- Relaxed breaking rules, e.g. `\sloppy` or `\begin{sloppypar}...\end{sloppypar}`. The price is bad line breaks, underfull lines ...
- Manual intervention, adding break or hyphenation points, reformulation of the text to get better line breaks.