# Hyphenation with Librebaskerville

Tags: hyphenation

I installed librebaskerville package and compiled a long text. I love the look of it, but at times words do not hyphen correctly, and a word gets out of the frame. It is hard to explain it, so I took a snapshot of an occurrence from the compiled file

[image]

Any folks here had the same problem? And how did you solve it if you had?

On top of that, I noticed that for some reasons footnote are not compiled using the baskerville font, but with the standard font. Also here, I have no idea of how to tweak the code!

Thanks!

Comment: Mhhh, is there any chance that you can show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), i.e. a full compilable document, of the bad hyphenation? Just that one paragraph with the problematic hyphenation would be enough.

Comment: The first line in a paragraph is always the most difficult one for TeX. I would ignore these `overfull \hbox` warnings during writing. Once the text is finished, I would try slight rewording to get a better line break. see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435343/overfull-hbox-warning for further possibilities.

Comment: FWIW `\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}

\begin{document}
The focus on individuals' rational behaviour has a strong methodological implication.
\end{document}` hyphenates at "meth-odological" for me, which seems fine according to M-W https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/methodological

Comment: If you trust Merriam-Webster, you can add `\hyphenation{meth-od-o-log-i-cal}` to your document preamble. If you use `babel` something slightly different is necessary.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45287384#45287384

Comment: @moewe I wouldn't trust Merriam-Webster for British hyphenation.

Comment: @cfr It's a bit of a gamble, but it was the only online source I could find with indicated hyphenations. Do you know of an online dictionary for BrE that does this?

Comment: @moewe Does barbara count?

Comment: @moewe, it is a book with hundreds of pages, and a very long preamble. I do not know how to make it into a workable example

Comment: We don't need to see the entire document and neither do we want to. It should still be possible to come up with a reasonably short [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) even if it comes from a long document. It may take some time to do so, but often it really helps to figure out where the problem lies. In this case you already got an answer even without an MWE, so it is not that pressing an issue. But in general you can't rely on that https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864

Comment: @moewe Here is a workable example \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\author{the author}

\begin{document}
\librebaskerville
\lipsum
The theory then invokes a  meta-agent, the `auctioneer', to mimic the functioning of markets.
\section{fdsfsd}
The second Welfare Theorem is particularly interesting, as it clearly bounds the field of investigation of the theory. Neoclassical economists only aim at understanding the conditions for maximising the efficiency of the economy, the `size of the pie.
\end{document}

Answer (score 4):

"methodological" (and its adverb, "-ly", as well as the noun "methodology"
and its plural) are not fully hyphenated by the existing tex patterns.

after egreg pointed out this question to me, i checked the exception list as
published in tugboat (and on ctan as the package
[hyphenex](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenex)) and found that "method meth-od" is
already there since 2011 (but without its plural, which i have now added).

the following entries will be added with the next update:

```
methods            meth-ods
methodology        meth-od-o-lo-gy
methodologies      meth-od-o-lo-gies
methodological     meth-od-o-logical
methodologically   meth-od-o-logically
```

curiously, "methodical" and its adverb are hyphenated correctly by the tex
patterns.  perhaps the pattern that permits this is what is blocking the
hyphenation of "methodology" and relatives.  for further exploration.

why the second half of "methodological" has no hyphens seems to be the
normal practice of this dictionary -- omit hyphens in later parts of compound
words.  i will continue to follow the guidance of the dictionary in entering
new items in the exception list, but note that, in this case at least, tex *will*
hyphenate the latter parts of all these words acceptably, so if it necessary to
add an exception on account of failure to hyphenate the "method" part, i would
have no hesitation adding hyphens in the "log-i-cal" part as well in the "local"
exception entry.

for those not familiar with the exception list, it shows the "standard" u.s.
hyphenation forms as given by merriam webster's 3rd new international dictionary,
print edition.  (the print edition is used rather than an online version as it
is advisable to have a fixed point for this endeavor.)  the intent of the list 
is to be a resource for words needed in a local `\hyphenation{...}` entry, and
for possible future updates of the patterns.

(i'm sorry, but i can't answer the second question, why footnotes are compiled
using a different font than the main text.  that might be a good candidate for
a separate question, where it would receive more attention.)